# Progress Bar Window / Bar in the notification area for a running shell script

Tags: scripts, notification, notification-area

I implemented some shell scripts to my dolphin context menue. Within the shells scripts i run some commands, which take some time.

My question is: Is it possible to implement some code into the (a) shell script, so that a pop up window or a status bar in the notification field (kde plasma) is showing up?

Here is the script i want to use the progress bar on:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir small
cp *.jpg small
cp *.JPG small
cd small

for i in *.jpg; do
 if [ -e "$i" ]; then
   file=`basename "$i" .jpg`
   mogrify -unsharp 0.25x0.25+8+0.065 -resize 1280x1024 -normalize -density 180 -monitor "$i"
 fi
done

for i in *.JPG; do
 if [ -e "$i" ]; then
   file=`basename "$i" .JPG`
   mogrify -unsharp 0.25x0.25+8+0.065 -resize 1280x1024 -normalize -density 180 -monitor "$i"
 fi
done
```

Explanation: The script is very handy to post-process pictures (jpegs) to a reasonable size for picture protocols (ppt, pdf, etc.) or whatelse...

Comment: For scripts there's `zenity` which has a progress bar, but that's done in Gtk and may not look good on KDE. For KDE there might be something else but I'm no KDE user so can't suggest

Comment: Okay...is the bar within the terminal or is there a seperate window opening?

Comment: It's a GUI popup. Basically works on the premise of piping percentage from a loop or subshell to the `zenity` command with appropriate flags. Here's an example: https://askubuntu.com/a/931015/295286

Comment: Thanks, but the script is just showing the bar but not the actual progress of the commands, which i filled in...Any suggestions

Comment: Well, there's not much to be done with commands themselves. If we're talking about commands like `cp` or `find` they're built to perform one specific function, and if there's no progress option - there's not much we can do.

Comment: Please edit that into the actual question. Comments support only very limited formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my question is working but not the most beautiful one ;) It lacks the continuous progress bar in percentage.

Add to the script:

```
 (#your commands) | zenity --progress --auto-close --title="Post-Process Pictures" --text="Rendering pictures..." --pulsate
```

This will open a window with the pulsating bar. The window is open as long as the commands are still working.

The Full script now looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

(mkdir small
cp *.jpg small
cp *.JPG small
cd small

for i in *.jpg; do
 if [ -e "$i" ]; then
   file=`basename "$i" .jpg`
   mogrify -unsharp 0.25x0.25+8+0.065 -resize 1280x1024 -normalize -density 180 -monitor "$i"
 fi
done

for i in *.JPG; do
 if [ -e "$i" ]; then
   file=`basename "$i" .JPG`
   mogrify -unsharp 0.25x0.25+8+0.065 -resize 1280x1024 -normalize -density 180 -monitor "$i"
 fi
done) | zenity --progress --auto-close --title="Post-Process Pictures" --text="Rendering pictures..." --pulsate
```

Best, Benjamin.

[image: Pulsating Progress Bar]

Beside: I use the script in combination with a .desktop file, so that i can use it via left-click context menue in dolphin. Just create a resize.desktop file in /usr/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Actions=resize_pictures
Icon=transform-crop-resize
MimeType=image/jpeg;
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
Type=Service
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel

[Desktop Action resize_pictures]
Exec=sh pathtoyourscript/resize_pictures
Icon=transform-scale
Name=Resize Image(s)
```